# Adding indexes to table

Tags: mysql, indexing

I have a datatable that gets the data from server side, and I want to optimize my table by adding indexes so that the sorting is faster (right now it takes around 7 seconds to sort 60K rows)

My 'copy create statement to clipboard' looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `email` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `password` char(128) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `salt` char(5) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `joined` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(60) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `surname` varchar(60) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `role` varchar(45) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `photo` varchar(45) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `user_type` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `user_owner` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `email` (`email`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=81634 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
```

The problem that I'm having is that if I use this:

```
ALTER TABLE `users` ADD INDEX (`email`, `name`, `surname`, `user_type`) ;
```

only email is indexed (at least only the email column can be sorted fast). I'm not sure what I can do to add the other indexed columns (or if it's actually going to be good for optimizing it).

Answer (score 1):

You have to add a separate index for each column you want to use.

But be aware: MySQL can only use an index for the where clause, or the order by. But not both at once. Unless, it is the same index for both. But in that case the where clause must be a constant (i.e. it must match a single value).

See also: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/order-by-optimization.html

Comment: It doesn't seem to work with a separate index for each column. In fact, if I just do ADD INDEX (email) this index won't do any good to the sorting, but if I do ADD INDEX(email, name, surname, user_type) then the email column is sorted almost instantly... Any ideas on why this happens?

Comment: @luqita Post an explain plan for both ways.

Comment: I don't understand your question... The explain shows the same thing for both ways :(

Comment: @luqita If the explain shows the same thing both ways then it will run at the same speed both ways. Do you know how to generate an explain?

Comment: @luqita No, explain select, not explain table. It gives you a table with info about how it's going to process the query. It's invaluable when trying to find the fastest way to do a query.

Comment: Ah ok... So with ADD INDEX(email, name, surname, user_type) it is-> id = 1, select_type = simple, table = users, type = ALL, possible_keys = NULL, key = NULL, key_len = NULL, ref = NULL, rows = 81729, Extra: Using filesort. This is the fast sorting. With only ADD INDEX (email) it is the same as the other one except that rows is 81681 (and this results in a slow sorting). The query is SELECT * FROM users ORDER by email.

Comment: @luqita No, the change in rows from 81729 to 81681 is meaningless. You have a full table scan plus filesort - i.e. the worst possible result. The reason the query may appear to be faster sometimes is that it gets cached. The change you made to the index is having no effect. It doesn't make sense though - it should be using the index for at least the sorting.

Comment: @luqita I found a bug report with this issue: http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=54225 looks like you need to force the index. `SELECT * FROM users FORCE INDEX(email) ORDER by email` The same things happens to be BTW - I was unable to get MySQL to use the index for sorting in any test, except by forcing it.

Comment: hmmm thanks, but i tested with force index and i get the same results (slow sort when the table has add index(email), and fast sort when it has add index(email, name, surname... etc)

Comment: @luqita Did you check for caching? Because that makes absolutely no sense.